# How can I compare 2 indexes in same list in Python?

Tags: python

```
code_length = len(morse_list)
morse_length = len(morse_code)

for i in range(code_length):
    for j in range(morse_length):
        if morse_list[i] == morse_code[j][1]:
            translated += morse_code[j][0]

    if morse_list[i] == '':
        translated += ' '

    elif morse_list[i] and morse_list[i+1] == '': <<<<<<<<<<<<
        translated += '\n'
```

IndexError: list index out of range.
What I am trying to do is, if there are two enters in-a-row on user input, I want to put enter(\n) which is after finish the N sentence. I am sure there is the better way but I can't figure it out. Any suggestions, please?

Edit for example, if in the list

```
['.-', '-...', '-.-.', '-..', '', '', '.', '..-.', '', '', '--.'],
```

> ```
> output: abcd\n ef\n g
> ```

Edit2,

```
morse_code = (
   ('a', '.-'), ('b', '-...'), ('c', '-.-.'), ('d', '-..'),
   ('e', '.'), ('f', '..-.'), ('g', '--.'), ('h', '....'), ('i', '..'),
   ('j', '.---'), ('k', '-.-'), ('l', '.-..'), ('m', '--'), ('n', '-.'),         
   ('o', '---'), ('p', '.--.'), ('q', '--.-'), ('r', '.-.'),
   ('s', '...'), ('t', '-'), ('u', '..-'), ('v', '...-'), ('w', '.--'),
   ('x', '-..-'), ('y', '-.--'), ('z', '--..')
)

morse_list = [] # user input words
```

Comment: You need to check `i + 1 < morse_length`

Comment: Use `enumerate` to avoid little error traps like these

Comment: I think `enumerate` won't help here, since `for i, e in enumerate (code_length):` will still result in `i` ranging from `0` to `len (morse_list) - 1`, as does the `range (code_length)` call.

Comment: can we get the `morse_list` and `morse_code` lists?

Comment: @vash_the_stampede just edited now.

Answer (score 2):

Your `morse_list [i + 1]` doesn't exist if `i == code_length - 1`,
since you then try to retrieve `morse_list [code_length]`.

The indexes only run from `0` to `code_length - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not satisfied with this, but it works and will get the output, some one about to school me haha

```
morse_code = ( 
   ('a', '.-'), ('b', '-...'), ('c', '-.-.'), ('d', '-..'),
   ('e', '.'), ('f', '..-.'), ('g', '--.'), ('h', '....'), ('i', '..'),
   ('j', '.---'), ('k', '-.-'), ('l', '.-..'), ('m', '--'), ('n', '-.'),             
   ('o', '---'), ('p', '.--.'), ('q', '--.-'), ('r', '.-.'),
   ('s', '...'), ('t', '-'), ('u', '..-'), ('v', '...-'), ('w', '.--'),
   ('x', '-..-'), ('y', '-.--'), ('z', '--..')
)

test = ['.-', '-...', '-.-.', '-..', '', '', '.', '..-.', '', '', '--.']

output = []
for index, item in enumerate(test):
    for a in morse_code:
        if item == a[1]:
            output.append(a[0])
        elif item == '' and test[index +1] == '':  
            output.append('\n')
            break
        else:
            pass
print(''.join(output))
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 morse.py 
> abcd
> ef
> g
> ```

Comment: Thank you! it helped me a lot!

Comment: @PhilipPark glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

I would put morse code into dict.

```
morse = {'.-': 'a',
         '-...': 'b',
         '-.-.': 'c',
         '-..': 'd',
         '': ' '}

morse_list = ['.-', '-...', '-.-.', '-..', '', '', '.-', '-...']
message = ''

for item in morse_list:
    message += morse[item]
    message = message.replace('  ', '\\n ')

print(message)
```

output: abcd\n ab

I see. Here is a list version. The 'if' can be removed from the loop if We could put this (' ','') into 'morse_code'.

```
morse_code = (
   ('a', '.-'), ('b', '-...'), ('c', '-.-.'), ('d', '-..'),
   ('e', '.'), ('f', '..-.'), ('g', '--.'), ('h', '....'), ('i', '..'),
   ('j', '.---'), ('k', '-.-'), ('l', '.-..'), ('m', '--'), ('n', '-.'),         
   ('o', '---'), ('p', '.--.'), ('q', '--.-'), ('r', '.-.'),
   ('s', '...'), ('t', '-'), ('u', '..-'), ('v', '...-'), ('w', '.--'),
   ('x', '-..-'), ('y', '-.--'), ('z', '--..')
)

morse_list = ['.-', '', '-...', '-.-.', '-..', '', '', '.-', '-...']

message = ''
for item in morse_list:
    if not item:
        message += ' '
        continue
    message += next(filter(lambda m: m[1] == item, morse_code))[0]

message = message.replace('  ', '\n')
print(message)
```

Comment: Thanks! I should stick with list on this problem but that's good to know with dict.